# The project is deploying on heroku but the bot doesn't get online

Tags: gradle, heroku, discord-jda

so I am trying to get my discord bot (jda/gradle) online from heroku using github, its deploying but not getting online. I checked the logs using `heroku logs -a APP` and it is giving a tons of errors on the imports, my understanding is it's not using the jda/gradle libraries, here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0' }

mainClassName = 'com.xlol.testbot.TestBot'

group 'com.xlol' version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 16

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name 'm2-dv8tion'
        url 'https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases'
    } }

task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean']) build.mustRunAfter clean

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'me.duncte123', name: 'botCommons', version: '1.0.45'

    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.3.0_324'
    implementation 'io.github.cdimascio:java-dotenv:5.1.1'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3' }


 compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: @TonyYip actually now it doesnt give an error but it still wont come online, here is the log:
`Build started by user (email)
Release v28 created by user (email)
Deploy 5558cdab by user (email)
Build succeeded`

Comment: @TonyYip nevermind, i had forgotten to setup a dyno, here it is:
`2021-10-19T03:49:40.624805+00:00 app[worker.1]: import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
2021-10-19T03:49:40.624831+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^                                          
2021-10-19T03:49:40.633555+00:00 app[worker.1]: src/main/java/com/xlol/testbot/TestBot.java:5: error: package net.dv8tion.jda.api does not exist`                          

there is like 15 more of the same error, different imports.

Answer (score 0):

This awnser seemed to be solved in [Heroku java app won't stay online for more than 90 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667907/heroku-java-app-wont-stay-online-for-more-than-90-seconds/69925493#69925493). Please close this post if you managed to solve the issue.